# Merging a Django1.5/python2 and a Django1.6/python3 app: ValueError at / need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to merge an existing Django app with an existing Django framework. This is causing some problems, as they were developed using different python/Django versions, but I'm getting on pretty well.

I'm running into a bug I can't seem to wrap my head around now though. I'm convinced I'm doing something wrong in the urls.py files, but I can't seem to figure out what exactly.
So, here's the error I'm getting:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/

Django Version: 1.6.4
Python Version: 3.4.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'kapstok',
 'forecast',
 'prefscan.survey',
 'prefscan.ipblocker',
 'prefscan.util',
 'prefscan.controlcenter')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  337.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  365.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  360.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  104.     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "/home/linus/fo/web-framework/pi/urls.py" in <module>
  13.     url(r'^prefscan/', include('prefscan.urls', namespace="prefscan")),
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py" in include
  26.         urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  104.     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "/home/linus/fo/web-framework/prefscan/urls.py" in <module>
  56. add_to_builtins('util.templatetags.closure_extras')
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in add_to_builtins
  1331.     builtins.append(import_library(module))
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in import_library
  1263.         if is_library_missing(taglib_module):
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in is_library_missing
  1247.         return is_library_missing(path)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in is_library_missing
  1247.         return is_library_missing(path)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in is_library_missing
  1242.     path, module = name.rsplit('.', 1)

Exception Type: ValueError at /
Exception Value: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Which seems to point to the `pi/urls.py` file. This file looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'pi.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^', include('kapstok.urls', namespace="kapstok")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^prefscan/', include('prefscan.urls', namespace="prefscan")),
)
```

Whenever I comment out the line `url(r'^prefscan/', ...),` the error goes away.

`prefscan/urls.py` looks like this:

```
import django

if django.VERSION < (1, 6):
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
else:
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.template.loader import add_to_builtins

import prefscan.controlcenter.urls
import prefscan.ipblocker.core

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin 
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^prefscan/$',                                        'survey.views.login'),

    url(r'^prefscan/cc/staff/siteadmin/',                      include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^prefscan/cc/' ,                                     include(prefscan.controlcenter.urls.urlpatterns)),

    url(r'^prefscan/survey/login/$',                           'survey.views.login'),
    url(r'^prefscan/survey/logout/$',                          'survey.views.logout'),
    url(r'^prefscan/language/(?P<language>[a-z]+)/$',          'survey.views.set_preferred_language'),
    url(r'^prefscan/survey/$',                                 'survey.views.choose'),
    url(r'^prefscan/survey/questionnaire/(?P<survey_id>\d+)/$','survey.views.questionnaire'),
    url(r'^prefscan/survey/(?P<survey_id>\d+)/$',              'survey.views.detail'),
    url(r'^prefscan/survey/pdf/(?P<survey_id>\d+)/$',          'survey.views.response_pdf'),

    url(r'^prefscan/survey/json/(?P<survey_id>\d+)/$',         'survey.views.json_get_assignment'),
    url(r'^prefscan/survey/json/list$',                        'survey.views.json_list_surveys'),
    url(r'^prefscan/survey/json/cards/(?P<survey_id>\d+)/$',   'survey.views.json_list_cards'),
    url(r'^prefscan/survey/json/shape/(?P<survey_id>\d+)/$',   'survey.views.json_list_shape'),
    url(r'^prefscan/survey/json/savequest/(?P<survey_id>\d+)/$','survey.views.json_store_questionnaire'),
    url(r'^prefscan/survey/json/store/(?P<survey_id>\d+)/$',   'survey.views.json_store_assignment'),
    url(r'^prefscan/survey/json/load/(?P<survey_id>\d+)/$',    'survey.views.json_load_assignment'),
    url(r'^prefscan/survey/json/send/(?P<survey_id>\d+)/$',    'survey.views.json_send_response'),
    url(r'^prefscan/survey/keepalive/$',                       'survey.views.keep_alive'),
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()

js_info_dict = {
    'domain': 'djangojs',
    'packages': ('js'),
}

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^jsi18n/$', 'django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog', js_info_dict),
)

urlpatterns += prefscan.ipblocker.core.urlpatterns

add_to_builtins('util.templatetags.closure_extras')
add_to_builtins('django.templatetags.i18n')
```

I'm just not seeing what's going wrong! The prefscan line seems identical to the kapstok line, which works without hiccups.

Comment: The error come from your `add_to_builtins('util.templatetags.closure_extras')` line specifically. What is `util.templatags.closure_extras`? You might have an error in this templatetags code in Python2